# Django: Hiding specific ForeignKey Objects

Tags: python, django

I've got these two models:

```py
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    club = models.ForeignKey('schedule.club', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    archived = models.DateTimeField('Archived at', blank=True, null=True)
```

```py
class Club(models.Model):
   archived = models.DateTimeField('Archived at', blank=True, null=True)
   some fields more fields
```

Now when creating a new `User` for the field `club` I can always pick from a list of all my club objects. But for my Clubs I've got a archive function which is inside my models.py and does the following:

```py
def archive(self, user):
        self.name = 'Archived Club'
        self.archived = now()
```

So they are not getting deleted. Only their data get anonymised and they basically still exist in the DB. And exactly those Clubs I don't want to see anymore when creating a new `User` and setting his/her club. Is there a way to do that without changing the club field in my form?

Thanks for anyone who can help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the attribute [`limit_choices_to`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.limit_choices_to) of a `ForeignKey`:

```
club = models.ForeignKey('schedule.club', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True,
    limit_choices_to={'archived__isnull': True})
```

Note that since `club` can be `None`, I would set `on_delete` to `SET_NULL` just to be sure. That way, if a club gets deleted for some reason, you don't loose all the users associated with it.